# Ajax Post with 2 url target

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Im trying to send a data into 2 different url with ajax in Jquery 
i can think something like this :

```
$.ajax({ 
type: 'POST' 
url: 'some_url1' 
data: 'some data'  
success: function(data){  
$.ajax ({  
type: 'POST'  
url: 'some_url2' 
data: 'some data' 
success: function(data){}
}) 
}  
})
```

is there any other way to do it ? 
thx

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but read http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15592/poor-practice-to-place-a-ajax-in-the-success-of-a-previous-ajax-call-ajax-type/ as helpful information for enqueuing multiple AJAX requests is there. Also I'd try to do the second AJAX request on the backend side. Unless you want both with non-dependency, you can run at the same time from JS.

Answer (score 5):

When you have code like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'some_url1',
  data: 'some data', 
  success: function(data){  
    $.ajax ({  
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'some_url2',
      data: 'some data',
      success: function(data){}
    });
  }
});
```

The very first thing that should jump out at you is the amount of duplication.  You essentially have two very nearly identical code blocks.  Unless there's a very good reason why it should be duplicated (for example, if the two code blocks are responsible to two different business owners/roles and are *very* likely to change independently of one another), then abstract the duplicated code into a single function.

In this case, there are only two differences between the two duplicated code blocks:

1. The URL
2. The success callback

So the function that you extract from the duplicated code should accept those two things as parameters:

```
var makeAjaxCall = function (url, success_callback) {
  $.ajax ({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: url,
    data: 'some data',
    success: success_callback
  });
};
```

Then your example would invoke the function like this:

```
makeAjaxCall(
  'some_url1',
  makeAjaxCall(
    'some_url2',
    function() {}
  )
);
```

Note that in your example you're passing a `data` parameter to the callback functions, though you're not using it.  Is this a minimal contrived example for the purpose of the question and, in reality, you are using that parameter?  If so then the extracted function will need to handle that as well.  But before you do so, you'll need to be a bit more explicit because your example is confusing in this regard and may behave in unexpected (or at least unintuitive) ways.  When your inner AJAX success callback receives its `data` parameter, do you want it to be the result of the inner AJAX call?  Or do you want it to be the `data` parameter which was passed to the function which contains the inner AJAX call?  The intent is unclear in the code.

Comment: data parameter is callback from ajax call, and not passed into inner AJAX call,

both call will have the same data  (wich is 'some data' variabel)

Comment: @DimasKholid: I don't think you understand what the `data` parameter in your callback function is.  Which might be good, if that means you're not using it, because that would also mean that you don't need it which simplifies the callback abstraction down to what I have here.  (Always simplify, only add features when they're actually needed, and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that has URL to be sent to in a parameter and then just call that function 2 times, every time with another URL, instead of writting double code...

Comment: I'm sorry, can u give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

It look's something like this..

```
$(function() {
     // Make the first ajax call with Parameters
     ajaxCall('firsturl' , firstdata , callbackFunction1 );

});

function callbackFunction1(result) {
    // Make the econd ajax call from the callback function1
     ajaxCall('secondurl' , seconddata , callbackFunction2 ); 
};

 function callbackFunction2(result) {
    // Success call back of second ajax request     
}; 

function ajaxCall(url, usrData, callbackFunction) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST'
        url: url,
        data: usrData,
        success: callbackFunction
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function ValidateForm() {     

    //Data Post to FirstForm
    var str = $("#FirstForm").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "https://xyz.com",
        data: str,
        success: function (msg) {console.log("Success data post ---->" + JSON.stringify(msg)) },
        error: function (msg) { console.log("Error data post ---->" + JSON.stringify(msg)) }

    });
    //End Data Post to First Form

    //Call Click event of Second form .Use Form post and action method .

       //Copy First Form text box  value into second Form text box 
      $("#btnSecondForm").trigger('click'); 
   //End Click event


  return false;
}



//Form in Body

<form  id="FirstForm" onsubmit="return ValidateForm(this)">

 //text box HTML 

</form>


 <form id="SecondForm" style='display:none' action="https://abc.com" method="post">

 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id='btnSecondForm' />

 </form>
```